# R : Fill in / map / plot a Shapefile with ggplot2, based on the values of a regoin

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile

Best

I've the following shapefile which is a map of Flanders (Belgium), and I would like to plot it with ggplot **with respect to** the **cheapestEnergyPrices**. (thus use a gradient colour)

```
head(flanders@data, n = 1)
  OBJECTID  Cs012011      Nis_   ...  Sec    Commune     Prov_nl    Reg_nl       cheapestEnergyPrices   mostExpensiveEnergyprices
  3         11001A00-     11001  ...  A00-   AARTSELAAR  Antwerpen  Vlaanderen   935.03                 1254.74


head(flanders@polygons, n=1)
[[1]]
An object of class "Polygons"
Slot "Polygons":
[[1]]
An object of class "Polygon"
Slot "labpt":
[1]  4.387485 51.132957

Slot "area":
[1] 6.825956e-05

Slot "hole":
[1] FALSE

Slot "ringDir":
[1] 1

Slot "coords":
           [,1]     [,2]
  [1,] 4.385794 51.13767
  [2,] 4.386132 51.13745
  ...  ...      ...
[147,] 4.385794 51.13767



Slot "plotOrder":
[1] 1

Slot "labpt":
[1]  4.387485 51.132957

Slot "ID":
[1] "0"

Slot "area":
[1] 6.825956e-05
```

At this point I've tried a lot of things, like e.g. the next piece of code :

```
> ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = flanders, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group,fill = flanders$cheapestEnergyPrices))
```

But unfortunately it will give me the next error code

```
Regions defined for each Polygons
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1224957): x, y, group, fill
```

Yet, when I replace **flanders$cheapestEnergyPrices** by **1**, like :

```
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = flanders, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group,fill = 1))
```

then I will get this unwanted result, because everything contains the same colour.

[image]

Thus ... I would like to plot my shapefile with ggplot2, whereby the polygones are coloured in, with respect to the value of e.g. cheapestEnergyPrices.
For example the *commune* which *cheapestEnergyPrice* is the lowest would have a DarkGreen colour and a *commune* who's *cheapestEnergyPrice* is much higher would have a light green / white, or even a red colour...

Comment: Will defining `cheapestEnergyPrices` as a `factor` change it?

Comment: This seems like a mistake: `geom_polygon(data = flanders, aes(..., fill = flanders$cheapestEnergyPrices))`. Since it's inside `aes`, you should just pass `fill = cheapestEnergyPrices`, and drop the `flanders$` prefix

Comment: ...but hard to help further since plot not reproducible from what you posted, without the shapefile

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = flanders, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = cheapestEnergyPrices))
```

I think you do not neet to repass `flanders$` but it's hard to tell without your data. As your column seems to be a numeric, the colour scale should follow.

I guess `flanders` is `fortify`-ed on the fly by `ggplot` and turned into a `data.frame`. A simpler alternative would be to:

i) turn `flanders` into a `data.frame` with `fortify` or [even better](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/fortify.html) `broom::tidy`

ii) use this `data.frame` with `ggplot2`, and other data manipulation.

Something like:

```
flanders_df <- broom::tidy(flanders)
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = flanders_df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = cheapestEnergyPrices))
```